# Shapiro-Wilk test: alpha inflation

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, p-value

In my master thesis, I include several variables (about 15). To decide wether to calculate parametric or non-parametric statistics, I want to test wether they are normally distributed. I decided to run the shapiro-wilk test in R. However, I was wondering wether there might be a risk of alpha inflation when running the test for 15 variables and if there is a correction formula for the p-value.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: "To decide wether to calculate parametric or non-parametric statistics, I want to test wether they are normally distributed." That's not a good strategy. I don't know what kind of statistics you are doing, but usually you should not care if the data passes a normality test. What is important is that the residuals of your statistics are "close enough" to normal. But that's not something a normality test tells you. Also, non-parametric tests have power-issues if your n isn't large.

Comment: I have a sample of 146 subjects. I want to calculate t-test and correlations. I read that the distribution of normality is an assumption for doing these tests, although they might be quite robust even if the data is not normally distributed

Comment: There is by far not enough information given in the question to provide sensible statistical advice (aside from the fact that this is generally not a good question for Stack Overflow, and may be a better fit for Cross Validated). Multiple t-tests are often not a good idea either, as it may lead you down the slippery slope of having to correct for mutliple-hypothesis testing and fishing for statistical significance etc. From what (little) I understand from your post & comment, perhaps a nested-effect model (with within-subject and between-subject effects) would make more sense. [...]

Comment: [continued] Since this is part of your master's thesis I would strongly recommend having a chat with your resident statistician and/or professor/supervisor/tutor. Developing a sensible statistical analysis strategy is something that can be a difficult task (as Andrew Gelman often puts it: [Statistics is hard](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2016/03/11/statistics-is-like-basketball-or-knitting/)) and should be critically discussed with peers/experts that have both statistics and domain-specific knowledge.